# Preventing evaluation until all undefined symbols are resolved

Tags: evaluation

```
FixedPoint[If[# <= 0, 0, # - 1]&, 2 x]
```

Causes an infinite loop because of 'x'. How do i automatically prevent evaluation until `2 x` is known? I have a similar function being fed into `Plot[]` and it has control over when `x` is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question leaves us all guessing, but *my* guess is that you want a combination of the answers already given.  I think you want to test the second argument of `FixedPoint` and only evaluate when this is numeric.  You could use:

```
fp[function_, start_?NumericQ] := FixedPoint[function, start]
```

Now this halts evaluation:

```
expr = fp[If[# <= 0, 0, # - 1] &, 2 x]
```

> ```
> fp[If[#1 <= 0, 0, #1 - 1] &, 2 x]
> ```

But after `x` is given a numeric value:

```
x = 5;
expr
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Interaction with `Plot` with a modified function:

```
Plot[fp[If[# <= 0, #, # - 1] &, 2 z], {z, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your use-case is not really clear. When you simply define a function from your expression, you can *control* that it is called with any expression which makes sense

```
myFixedPoint[x_] := FixedPoint[If[# <= 0, 0, # - 1] &, 2 x]
```

Let's say now you have an expression for `x` which doesn't end in an infinite loop, you can call

```
y = 3;
myFixedPoint[7 y]

(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
ClearAll[x]
f[x_] := FixedPoint[If[# <= 0, 0, # - 1] &, 2 x ];
myFixedPoint = Function[x, If[NumberQ[x], f[x], Undefined]];

myFixedPoint[x]
myFixedPoint[123.4]
x = 123.4
myFixedPoint[x]
```

with output

```
Undefined
0
123.4
0
```