# How avoid error message with Range?

Tags: replacement, rule

Evaluating

```
     Range[1, n] /. n -> 3
```

produces an error message

```
 range::range: Range specification in Range[1,n] does not have appropriate bounds
```

even though it does produce correct output `{1, 2, 3}`.

What's a good way to accomplish the same thing while avoiding the error message?

Comment: `ReplaceAll` or `/.` does not hold its arguments, so `Range[1, n]` is evaluated with symbolic `n` first.

Comment: Because it first evaluates `Range[1,n]` which is not very miningful and only then substitutes n->3 `With[{n=3},Range[1,n]]` could be more appropriate or `R[n_]:=Range[1,n]; R[3]` or as suggested by @ilian

Comment: Yet `Attributes[ReplaceAll]` gives no `Hold` attributes!

Comment: @murray that is exactly what illian says...

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "no" in illian's comment. All is clear now, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(39055)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39055/121)

Comment: Use `Unevaluated@Range[1, n] /. n -> 3`.  Do you need explanation on why it works despite the error message (or why it gives an error message despite the fact that it works)?

Comment: @Szabolcs: ilian already gave an explanation that satsfies me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your updated question I think you want to hold evaluation until all arguments are numeric.

```
myRange[x__?NumericQ] := Range[x]

myRange[1, n] /. n -> 3
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```